# didTapInfoWindowOfMarker not executing

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to simply get the coordinates of a marker that has been selected by the user to then use in Google Maps. However I can not get my didTapInfoWindowOfMarker function to call ("Called didTap" is never printed to console) when the user taps the marker's info window, and thus can not acquire the coordinates of the tapped marker.

Here is my code:

```
extension MapViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapInfoWindowOfMarker marker: GMSMarker!) {
       print("Called didTap")
       let googleMarker = mapView.selectedMarker
       let markerValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = googleMarker.position
       let markerLat = markerValue.latitude
       let markerLong = markerValue.longitude
       print("markerLat: \(markerLat)")
       print("markerLong: \(markerLong)")
       mapView.selectedMarker = nil
       mapView.delegate = self
    }
 }
```

Comment: You must set the delegate.

Comment: Set which delegate to what? @nhgrif

Comment: The map view's delegate to self.

Comment: I've already done that in viewDidLoad(). @nhgrif

Comment: Fixed it. Had to change mapView.delegate = self to self.mapView.delegate = self.
Thank you for replying @nhgrif!